# Find() returns "object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, find

This block of code was working fine but I deleted some lines above Find() that broke it.  Any ideas?

```
Sub CopySheet()
      Dim TotalRow As Integer
      
      Set NurselineBook = ThisWorkbook
      TotalRow = Range("$C:$C").Find(What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
      Range("A1:L" & TotalRow).Select
      Range("Ah1").Activate
      Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
      
      MsgBox "Dashboard Copied"
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe nothing was found? You should set the results of the `Find` to a variable you can check first before you get the `Row` property from it.

Comment: This error occurred because the text wasn't found. Find uses the settings of the last find even if this was done through the find dialog on the spreadsheet. Check the find dialog settings to make sure they are what you expect. You can avoid this issue by using all the Find parameters.

Comment: Also Note: Your `Find` is being done on the `ActiveWorksheet` because your `Range` is not qualified. You set `NurselineBook` but then you never use it, so you probably want something more like `NurselineBook.ActiveSheet.Range.Find`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyTable()
      
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const ColumnsAddress As String = "A:L"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 3
    Const gtString As String = "Grand Total"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With ws.Columns(ColumnsAddress)
        Set srg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1).Offset(FirstRow - 1)
    End With
    
    Dim gtcell As Range: Set gtcell = srg.Columns(CriteriaColumn) _
        .Find(gtString, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    If gtcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find '" & gtString & "'.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = srg.Resize(gtcell.Row - FirstRow + 1)
    
    drg.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    
    MsgBox "Dashboard Copied", vbInformation

End Sub
```